# Tableau - How to Iterate Over a List (Loops/If Statements/CASE) to Create a Dynamic Summary of Financial Data

Tags: loops, if-statement, tableau-api, iterable, tableau-desktop

I'm a beginner in Tableau and in programming in general. I'm developing a dynamic dashboard in Tableau, in which I need to have a calculated field that dynamically summarizes financial data. Currently, my data is outputting as follows:

```
Summary of Data
*$0 - $100 = 2%
*$100 - $200 = 5%
*$200 - $300 = 6%
*$200 - $300 = 6%
*$200 - $300 = 6%
*$300 and above = 6%
```

The code for the summary:

```
"Summary of Data" + char(10) +
"• $0" + " - "+ " - $" + STR([Amt1]) + " = " + STR([Discount0]) + "%" + char(10) + 
"• $" + STR([Amt1]) + " - $" + STR([Amt2]) + " = " + STR([Discount1]) + "%" + char(10)+
"• $" + STR([Amt2]) + " - $" + STR([Amt3]) + " = " + STR([Discount2]) + "%" + char(10)+
"• $" + STR([Amt3]) + " - $" + STR([Amt4]) + " = " + STR([Discount3]) + "%" + char(10)+
"• $" + STR([Amt4]) + " - $" + STR([Amt5]) + " = " + STR([Discount4]) + "%" + char(10)+
"• $" + STR([Amt5]) + " - $" + STR([Amt6]) + " = " + STR([Discount5]) + "%" + char(10)+
"• $" + STR([Amt6]) + " and above " + " = " + STR([Discount6]) + "%"
```

As you can see, there are some duplications. The system will populate six discounts and six thresholds, and these vary based on the deal. So, some deals may have duplications, while others do not. I wish to write some code that removes the duplicate lines; for example, the above example would become:

```
Summary of Data
* $0 - $100 = 2%
*$100 - $200 = 5%
*$300 and above = 6%
```

below is my current code using IF statements:

```
"Summary of Data" + char(10) +
"• $0" + " - "+ " - "+ STR([Amt 1]) + " = " + STR([Discount0]) + "%" + char(10) +
If ([Amt2] > [Amt1] and [Discount1] > [Discount0]) 
THEN "• $" + STR([Amt 1]) + " - $" + STR([Amt2]) + "      = " + STR([Discount1]) + "%" + char(10) 
ELSEIF ([Amt3] > [Amt2] and [Discount2] > [Discount1]) 
THEN "• $" + STR([Amt3]) + " - $" + STR([Amt4]) + " = " + STR([Discount3]) + "%" + char(10) 
ELSEIF ([Amt4] > [Amt3] and [Discount3] > [Discount2]) 
THEN "• $" + STR([Amt4]) + " - $" + STR([Amt5]) + " = " + STR([Discount4]) + "%" + char(10)  
ELSEIF ([Amt5] > [Amt5] and [Discount5] > [Discount3]) 
THEN "• $" + STR([Amt6]) + " and above  = " + STR([Discount6]) + "%" + char(10) END
```

I have tried to make a While do loop (which does not seem to be supported in Tableau), a CASE (which I couldn't get to work) and IF statements. I expected my IF statements to return all the lines of code before it "exited" the if statement; however, it seems to only return the last one (in addition to the first one). My solution would be to use a loop, but that does not seem to be supported. I have also had extended conversations with openAI about the code, and "he" seems as confused as I am!